# Remotely manage Hyper-V VMs - Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v

I have a desktop Windows 10 machine not on any domain which I use as a Hyper-V host to many VMs. This has a wired connection to my router. I also have a laptop which I use wirelessly only (it connects to the same router in my house). The laptop has Hyper-V enabled on it as well. I would like to connect to / manage the Hyper-V VMs on my desktop from my laptop. On my laptop, I tried going to "connect to server" and putting in the ip address of my desktop, and I'm getting the following error:

"An error occurred while attempting to connect to server "192.168.0.48". Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server. The computer '192.168.0.48' could not be resolved. Make sure you typed the machine name correctly and that you have network access."

I can successfully ping 192.168.0.48 from my laptop. I've also disabled the firewall to rule that out.

Any thoughts / comments / help gratefully received! Thanks in advance

Comment: Remotely typically means managing a computer system from outside of it's an internal network.  What you describe wouldn't typically be called remotely managing a virtual machine.  You are attempting to connect to the server, which will manage the VMs, instead of trying to remotely log into the individual VMs (VMs would be remotely logged into since you would be accessing them not from the server but directly).

Comment: Hi Ramhound

Thanks for that, and apologies for using the wrong words. What I'm really looking to do is to use my laptop to connect to the VMs on my desktop, without having to be sat at my desktop. If possible, I don't really want to connect to my desktop at all - I just want to connect directly to the VMs that are hosted on my desktop, from my laptop. Does that make sense?

Thanks again

Comment: Microsoft has software solutions similar to VSphere, allowing to connect to a Hyper-V server, and displaying the console of a VM on the desktop which runs said client software.

Comment: The process you're using seems to be fine (assuming the laptop is Win10 also) but if you have already checked that the Virtual Machine Manager service is running on the laptop, then it is probably associated with the account you are using on the laptop.  Is it the same login on both systems?  Can you RDP to the desktop?  Open the files in File Explorer? Have you made the account a local administrator?  PING is only of minimal use since it simply says essentially that the laptop can confirm the desktop is alive, but not whether you have any rights to connect to it.

Comment: You need to allow the remote computer access to the Hyper-V management.  There's more to this than just networking.  There are lengthy articles that describe this.  What would be easier is to use RDP and connect to Windows 10 instead of Hyper-V.  If you want to do remote Hyper-V management, start here: https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/how-to-set-up-hyper-v-remote-management/